# How to call controller function in cron magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2.6, magento-cron

I have created a custom module and created the cron in magento 2.2.6

**crontab.xml** Learning\GreetingMessage\etc\crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="index">
<job name="samplecron" instance="Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron\Test" method="execute">
<schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
</group>
</config>
```

**Test.php** Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron\Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron;

class Test {

    protected $_logger;
    protected $_test;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        **\Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text $text**
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_test = $test;
    }

    /**
     * Method executed when cron runs in server
     */
    public function execute() {
        **$this->_test->execute();**
        $this->_logger->debug('Running Cron from Test class');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have controller in Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text.php

It is not working . it says `Class Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text does not exist` message in cron_schedule table

Comment: You have given instance="Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron\Test" and checking in controller file. You need to create the file at path Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron with name Test.php and create execute method in that file. Also make sure cron is working on your setup. You can execute crons by running command :  php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: @himmat , i already created Test.ph file for cron  (That one is pasted in my question). i have Test.php controller also. i already execute php bin/magento cron:run. my cron joab name is also created in "cron_schedule" table. in the table they show message as "Class Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text does not exist".
But the controller class is their

Comment: @himmat if i remove controller call lines from my cron file. it executed with success message

Comment: May be, basically you don't need controller action to run cron. what you need is Test.php at given path. Please check my answer below..

Comment: Check my answer and follow the steps as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this flow and set file name as per your requirement :

**Create a file to run cron :**

> /var/www/html/Magento2/app/code/Learning/GreetingMessage/Cron/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Test {
  protected $logger;
  public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }
  /**
    * Write to system.log
    *
    * @return void
  */
  public function execute() {
    // Do your Stuff
    $this->logger->info('cron working successfully');
  }
}
```

**Create crontab.xml**

> /var/www/html/Magento2/app/code/Learning/GreetingMessage/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">

<group id="default">
    <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron\Test" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

**Now, execute command :**

> php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: this is working fine for me. i have a problem while call controller function inside the cron execute() method

Comment: I have a controller in "Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text.php" with function execute. i need to call the controller execute function in cron.

Comment: change instance in crontab.xml file => instance="Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text"

Comment: I changed and run php bin/magento setup:upgrade ,rm -rf generated/,php bin/magento cache:flush, php bin/magento cron:run --group index , sudo chmod -R 777  .   I table have message "Class Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Text does not exist" and status : 'running'

Comment: But class is there. while i call the url "http://localhost/magento/helloworld/index/test" . it is working properly. my controller have namespace "namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index;"

Comment: if you add controller path in construct then please remove it.

Comment: is it working ..?

Comment: Yes , now it is working thank you for sharing knowledge.

Comment: Happy to Help !! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
<job name="samplecron" instance="Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron\Test" method="execute">
<schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
</group>
</config>
```

Create Test.php file at below path:
Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron with

put below code in Test.php

```
<?php 
namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron;

class Test {

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Method executed when cron runs in server
     */
    public function execute() {
        $this->_logger->debug('Running Cron from Test class');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: i already did this code in "Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron" path. I use same name for both controller and cron instance .

Comment: I edited my question please look